# Invalid signature exception during zappa deploy with gitlab CI/CD

Tags: python-3.x, flask, zappa

I am having a problem with deploying my flask app aws via zappa in gitlab CI/CD.
First time i tried it got deployed correctly, but every other try finishes with this exception.

manual deploy from commandline works just fine
the actual error starts while uploading packaged application to aws

Actual gitlab-ci is

```
image: python:3.6-buster

stages:
  - test
  - deploy-test


cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip

.virtualenv_deploy_setup_template: &virtualenv_deploy_setup
  before_script:
    - pip install virtualenv
    - virtualenv ~/zappa
    - source ~/zappa/bin/activate
    - pip install -r requirements.txt


    deploy-test:
  <<: *virtualenv_deploy_setup
  variables:
    ZAPPA_STAGE: test
  stage: deploy-test
  script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.aws
    - echo "[default]" >> ~/.aws/credentials
    - echo "aws_access_key_id = "$(echo $DEPLOY_AUTH | cut -f1 -d' ') >> ~/.aws/credentials
    - echo "aws_secret_access_key = "$(echo $DEPLOY_AUTH | cut -f2 -d' ') >> ~/.aws/credentials
    - mv "$ZAPPA_SETTINGS" "$(pwd)/zappa_settings.json"
    - flask db upgrade
    - zappa update $ZAPPA_STAGE || zappa deploy $ZAPPA_STAGE
  after_script:
    - rm ~/.aws/credentials
    - rm zappa_settings.json
  only:
    - develop
    - master
  when: manual
```

Full stack trace is

```
 Oh no! An error occurred! :(
 ==============
 ==============
 Need help? Found a bug? Let us know! :D
 File bug reports on GitHub here: https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa
 And join our Slack channel here: https://slack.zappa.io
 Love!,
  ~ Team Zappa!
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/root/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 753, in deploy
     function_name=self.lambda_name)
   File "/root/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/core.py", line 1286, in get_lambda_function
     FunctionName=function_name)
   File "/root/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
   File "/root/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 626, in _make_api_call
     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
 botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the GetFunction operation: Signature expired: 20200630T120625Z is now earlier than 20200630T120627Z (20200630T121127Z - 5 min.)
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/root/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 2778, in handle
     sys.exit(cli.handle())
   File "/root/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 512, in handle
     self.dispatch_command(self.command, stage)
   File "/root/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 549, in dispatch_command
     self.deploy(self.vargs['zip'])
   File "/root/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 786, in deploy
     self.lambda_arn = self.zappa.create_lambda_function(**kwargs)
   File "/root/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/core.py", line 1069, in create_lambda_function
     response = self.lambda_client.create_function(**kwargs)
   File "/root/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
   File "/root/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 626, in _make_api_call
     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
 botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: Signature expired: 20200630T120625Z is now earlier than 20200630T120627Z (20200630T121127Z - 5 min.)
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61477856/1014508

but I kind of have a feeling you are using that answer already as the base of your own gitlab config. In any case, there are multiple unknowns that you can share, ie. what's the value of `$ZAPPA_SETTINGS` and why are you moving it, the full error returned in gitlab, your project dir structure...

Comment: yes, i was using your as a base for my gitlab-ci file, $ZAPPA_SETTINGS is zappa_settings.json file but i am pretty sure everything is fine with it, because it worked the first time i tried deploying. I've added full stack trace to my question.

Comment: could you also post your zappa_settings.json? Though this `Signature expired` error looks like a host system time issue o.O

Comment: Unfortunately i can't post zappa_settings.json, and i'll try to resolve the host system time issue. It seems weird for me that newly created container on gitlab pipeline would have some time abnormality.

Answer (score 2):

Solution was very trivial, thanks to mr. @mislavcimpersak i tried syncing container's timezone with aws region i was deploying to.
EDIT:

```
  stage: deploy-test
  script:
    - apt update
    - apt install ntpdate
    - ntpdate de.pool.ntp.org
```

this piece of config added to gitlab-ci deploy stage fixed it